# Intellij different behavior depends on deployed war exploded or not

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jboss, jaxb

I see strange behavior in Intellij and JBoss server. 
Short info about application:

```
- spring 4.3.1
- jersey 1.18.1
- jboss EAP 6.4.0
```

I have an issue with marshaling, so I tried to dig deeper and try hints from: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Content_Marshalling_Providers.html

So I created class:

```
@Named
@Provider
@Primary
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JerseyJAXBConfiguration implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class[] types = { SomeClass.class};

    public JerseyJAXBConfiguration() throws Exception {

        JSONConfiguration.MappedBuilder builder = JSONConfiguration.mapped();
        builder.arrays("invite");
        builder.rootUnwrapping(false);
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(builder.build(), types);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        for (Class type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I have two JBoss run configurations in IntelliJ. First that deploy simple 'war' and second that deploy 'war exploded'. And here is a strange thing. Because in both cases this bean is loaded when the application is starting, but only for a case without exploded 'getContext' method is executed. In both cases, everything is the same. Nothing in code is changed between runs.
Can someone explain to me why we have this different? I would like to know what JAXB implementation is executed in a case for 'war exploded'.

The main reason why I looking at it is because Json that is created by web service also is different in metioned cases. On have "named" array second don't have.

In case 'war':

```
{"functionGroupAutoFill": [
  {
    "desc": "0. General",
    "id": "0"
  },
  {
    "desc": "00. General",
    "id": "00"
  },
 ...
 ]}
```

In case 'war exploded':

```
  [
      {
        "desc": "0. General",
        "id": "0"
      },
      {
        "desc": "00. General",
        "id": "00"
      },
     ...
     ]
```

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: From deployment perspective, execution of both the wars should be identical. If you are using maven, reimport the project and check.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I'm using mvn and I reimported and built the project under IntelliJ - nothing changed.